# jquery clone() content from iframe

Tags: jquery, clone

Originally I would like to transfer some content (div class="StaffBlock") which is loaded from the iframe from remote page into div class="Contact-Agent-Append". but the append() method is proved not working for the iframe. nomally it works but since I'm using template and the template is not a still page, I think that;s why the append() can't take the content into the current page. then I noticed the clone() is working but it will accidentially repeat 20 clones of the content. please help me make it clone once only. Many many thanks.

**this is the original coding that contain the iframe:**

```
<div class="Contact-Agent-{tag_Publish As Agent}">

    <div class="Contact-Agent-Small-Logo-listing" title="this property is published by agent">
    </div>
    <iframe scrolling="no" height="60px" frameborder="0" width="150px" src="{tag_listing agent staff url}" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px" style="overflow:hidden; margin:0; padding:0; display: none;"></iframe>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function(){
    $('iframe').contents().find('.StaffBlock').clone().appendTo($('.Contact-Agent-Append'))
    });//]]>
    </script> 
    <div class="Contact-Agent-Append">content should go here
    </div>

</div>
```

**this is the content stored in the remote url which contain the StaffBlock:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/StyleSheets/listing-contact.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="listing-contact">
<div class="StaffBlock">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="col-a">{tag_name}</td>
    <td class="col-b" rowspan="4">{tag_Staff Photo}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{tag_job title}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{tag_mobile}</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="mailto:{tag_email}">email me</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have multiple divs with the `Contact-Agent-Append` class?

Instead of using an invisible iframe you should use AJAX:

```
$(".Contact-Agent-Append").load("{tag_listing agent staff url} .StaffBlock:first");
```

> .load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )
>
> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments